# video capture card (webcam like) with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, webcam, video-capture, uvc

I want to use video capture card to capture my screen display, and process the image by OpenCV/C++.

I have heard that there's some video capture card which is webcam like.(i.e. I can get the screen display by VideoCapture in OpenCV.)

Can someone tell me which video capture card should I buy?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Could you be more specific about the capture card? Do you want a LVDS frame grabber, A MIPI to USB converter, ... ?

Comment: @ Alper Kucukkomurler hi, sorry for the late reply. The capture card I want to buy is a pcie capture card. If the pcie capture card is in pc B, the input of the capture card is from pc A via HDMI (the display which I want to capture.), and the output of the capture card need to be captured by pc B which is considered as webcam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there some way to achieve that directly using OpenCV. However, a simple workaround could be like this:

1. Using this software you can create new webcam that stream your screen: https://sparkosoft.com/how-to-stream-desktop-as-webcam-video
2. Using OpenCV you can start capture the stream using this code:

   ```
   cv::VideoCapture cap;
   if(!cap.open(0)) // Use the new webcam Id instead of 0
       return 0;
   while(true){
         cv::Mat frame;
         cap >> frame;
         if(frame.empty()) break;
         cv::imshow("Screen", frame);
         if( waitKey(10) == 27 ) break;
   }
   return 0;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! But I'm going to stream my screen display to six monitors, I'm wondering if this could afford it or not...

Back to your answer, so if I use this app, I can create my own webcam ID and display it in OpenCV? How can I know the device ID?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps now. But i found a way using opencv.
In linux and python, we achieve this using the following piece of code.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')
```