# HDMI-USB Video Capture Card Stream Using Opencv or any other library in Python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I am trying to read the stream from HDMI-USB video-capture card using opencv. But OpenCV doesn't seem to support that functionality. I used opencv to read RTSP streams and webcams. Can anyone suggest a way here. Currently I am accessing the stream using **OBS Studio** software. Is there any other module in python that I can use. Thanks in advance.

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133203/video-capture-card-webcam-like-with-opencv). But that approach doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
video0 or video1 depends on your system and connected devices.

Turns out we can access this USB device using opencv itself.
In linux you can access these devices at **/dev/video0**.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0')
```

I'm yet to figure out how to do this in windows though